# OpenGL Driver Update Windows 10

Tags: windows, opengl, nvidia, drivers

I have a GeForce GTX 660 that according to the NVIDIA site it supports OpenGL Drivers up to 4.3, now my problem is that windows sees only version 1.1 and i can't find a way to update the driver.

I've installed the latest drivers as of today 398.82 doing a regular update and a clean install with and without GeForce Experience but OpenGL still is 1.1

How can the OpenGL be forced to update to the latest version?

Please advise,

Edit
OpenGL Extensions Viewer 5.1.4 Results

```
Renderer: GDI Generic
Vendor: Microsoft Corporation
Memory: 2048 MB
Version: 1.1.0
Shading language version: N/A


Max texture size: 1024 x 1024
Max texture coordinates: 0
Max vertex texture image units: 0
Max texture image units: 0
Max geometry texture units: 0
Max anisotropic filtering value: 0
Max number of light sources: 8
Max viewport size: 16384 x 16384
Max uniform vertex components: 0
Max uniform fragment components: 0
Max geometry uniform components: 0
Max varying vectors: 0
Max samples: 0
Max draw buffers: 0


GL Extensions: 3
\i0 

GL_WIN_swap_hint
GL_EXT_paletted_texture
GL_EXT_bgra

Core features
v1.1 (100 % - 7/7)
v1.2 (12 % - 1/8)
v1.3 (0 % - 0/9)
v1.4 (0 % - 0/15)
v1.5 (0 % - 0/3)
v2.0 (0 % - 0/10)
v2.1 (0 % - 0/3)
v3.0 (0 % - 0/23)
v3.1 (0 % - 0/8)
v3.2 (0 % - 0/10)
v3.3 (0 % - 0/10)
v4.0 (0 % - 0/14)
v4.1 (0 % - 0/7)
v4.2 (0 % - 0/13)
v4.3 (0 % - 0/23)
v4.4 (0 % - 0/10)
v4.5 (0 % - 0/11)
v4.6 (0 % - 0/11)
vARB 2015 (0 % - 0/12)
OpenGL driver version check (Current: 0, Latest known: ):
 Latest version of display drivers found 
 According the database, you are running the latest display drivers for your video card.
 No multitexturing support 
 This may cause performance loss in some applications.
 No secondary color support 
 Some applications may not render polygon highlights correctly.
 No S3TC compression support 
 This may cause performance loss in some applications.
 No texture edge clamp support 
 This feature adds clamping control to edge texel filtering. Some programs may not render textures correctly (black line on borders.)
 No vertex program support 
 This feature enables vertex programming (equivalent to DX8 Vertex Shader.) Some current or future OpenGL programs may require this feature.
 No fragment program support 
 This feature enables per pixel programming (equivalent to DX9 Pixel Shader.) Some current or future OpenGL programs may require this feature.
 No OpenGL Shading Language support 
 This may break compatibility for applications using per pixel shading.
 No Frame buffer object support 
 This may break compatibility for applications using render to texture functions.
 Few texture units found 
 This may slow down some applications using fragment programs or extensive texture mapping.
Extension verification: 
 GL_EXT_color_subtable  was not found, but has the entry point  glColorSubTableEXT
```

Comment: How do you get to know the OpenGL version, as "seen from Windows"?

Comment: Are you referring the context version reported by OpenGL in your program, or the actual version number of the library? I am guessing you might need to look into how an OpenGL context is created.

Comment: @Ripi2 went to [OpenGL Getting Started](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Getting_Started) and installed one of the recommended OpenGL Viewers [OpenGL Extension Viewer](http://realtech-vr.com/admin/glview) and it tells me 1.2 and up are not supported

Comment: @ForeverZer0 the actual version installed/running on windows

Comment: Edit your question and add the result of GLview. It may help. Anyhow, that's a weird issue. Do you have another gfx card installed (e.g. an integrated one)?

Comment: @Ripi2 no, i don't have any other card, i did update from 7 to 10 though that's the only out of the ordinary thing i have done

Comment: I think you are confusing what "installed/running on windows" and "reported version" mean in regards to OpenGL. It will default to use lowest possible version for compatibility unless specified otherwise, typically with context hints for whatever app you are using to create the context. 1.1 is over two decades old. And BTW, welcome to the hell of OpenGL family versioning if you plan to write code with it.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 i've included my results, it looks like i don't even have the core features installed to use the other versions. And thank you for the warm welcome lol i'm not planning to write code just use some apps

Comment: It seems to not be recognizing your card, appears to be using integrated or emulated graphics, not NVIDIA. No NVIDIA extensions listed, and labeled as "generic". It should list your card there. Dumb question, but did you restart after updating drivers? If so, try another GL viewer.

Comment: OK. Try: First unistall all Nvida video driver. Delete any reference to any Nvidia driver, being it a dir or a entry in the registry (some reg-cleaner may help). Re-start Windows, let it use a default, not Nvidia, driver. Install the lastest Nvidia driver. If this does not work yet, try with an older driver version.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 this is going to be one of those embarrassing situations that nobody wants to admit but have to for future people to learn. Remote Desktop is NOT your friend when trying to use OpenGL. Logged directly into the machine and I can see OpenGL 4.3 and all the others

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL Does not run correctly while using Remote Desktop, it will take your OpenGL configuration to the lowest possible setting in my case 1.1. Logged in directly to the machine and everything started working just fine.

Comment: If you're wanting to do high performance GPU things remotely, I'm guessing you are on a LAN?  nVidia and Steam both have "In-Home Streaming" features that provide network access with full GPU support (albeit only to clients on the same LAN)